# drizzle-orm error: column "created_at" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone

Tags: typescript, timestamp, database-schema, next.js13, drizzle

This is my schema.ts file

```
export const messages = pgTable("messages", {
  id: serial("id").primaryKey(),
  chatId: integer("chat_id")
    .references(() => chats.id)
    .notNull(),
  content: text("content").notNull(),
  createdAt: timestamp("created_at").notNull().defaultNow(),
  role: userSystemEnum("role").notNull(),
});
```

It is throwing error as:

```
error: column "created_at" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (A:\sark and other\chatpdf-yt-main\node_modules\drizzle-kit\index.cjs:40722:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (A:\sark and other\chatpdf-yt-main\node_modules\drizzle-kit\index.cjs:40563:25)     
    at Parser.parse (A:\sark and other\chatpdf-yt-main\node_modules\drizzle-kit\index.cjs:40487:34)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (A:\sark and other\chatpdf-yt-main\node_modules\drizzle-kit\index.cjs:40763:44)   
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 231,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42804',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: 'You might need to specify "USING created_at::timestamp without time zone".',
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'tablecmds.c',
  line: '12302',
  routine: 'ATPrepAlterColumnType'
}
```

For role also showing same error:

```
export const userSystemEnum = pgEnum("user_system_enum", ["system", "user"]);
hint: 'You might need to specify "USING role::user_system_enum".'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to restructure the createdAt, i'm not really sure about what is wrong here. but maybe this would work:

```
  createdAt: timestamp("created_at").defaultNow().notNull(),
```

Answer (score 0):

As the hint suggests, append `USING created_at::timestamp without time zone` to the line of the generated SQL file that alters that column. So for your example you would change:

`ALTER TABLE "messages" ALTER COLUMN "created_at" SET DATA TYPE timestamp without time zone`

to

`ALTER TABLE "messages" ALTER COLUMN "created_at" SET DATA TYPE timestamp without time zone USING ("created_at"::timestamp without time zone)`